# python pandas cut in scala

Tags: python, scala, pandas

How can `pd.cut` (bucketing of an array given some splits),
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html

> ```
> >>> pd.cut(np.array([1, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3]), 3)
> ... 
> [(0.994, 3.0], (5.0, 7.0], (3.0, 5.0], (3.0, 5.0], (5.0, 7.0], ...
> Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(0.994, 3.0] < (3.0, 5.0] ...
> ```

i.e. the separation of an Array

```
Seq(1, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3)
```

into bins, given a list of splits

```
Seq(3,5)
```

be accomplished in scala?

## edit

Maybe the reference to the pandas documentation is misleading / not clear enough.
I want to separate the specified array ( assume integers) into groups (buckets) from:

```
[b_1, b_2, ...b_n[
```

I.e. in this case with 2 bucketing conditions receive `n+1` groups something similar to:

```
Seq(("[0-3]", Seq(1,3)),("4-5", Seq(4,5)), ("is 6-[", Seq(7))
```

i.e. assign a continuous range of numbers to discrete groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. Pandas `cut` takes eight parameters, most of which are optional with a default meaning or value, and some of which can accept differing data types (e.g. `bins` which can be `Int` or `Seq[Int]`). I assume you're not looking for something to imitate all that various behavior. That would probably be more code than most SO denizens are willing to contribute.

Here's a simple little something that, I think, gets at what you describe in the **edit** portion of your question.

```
def pdCut(x :Seq[Int], bins :Seq[Int]) :Seq[(String,Seq[Int])] = {
  val bs = bins.sorted.foldRight(Seq(("@",Seq(Int.MaxValue)))){case (b,v) =>
    val (str,sq) = v.head
    (s"$b", Seq(b)) +: (s"$b-$str", b +: sq) +: v.tail
  }
  val (str,sq) = bs.head
  val xs = (s"@-$str", Int.MinValue +: sq) +: bs.tail
  x.map(n => xs.find(_._2(1) >= n).get)
}
```

You might replace `Int.MinValue` with `0` if negative numbers aren't an issue.

Usage:

```
pdCut(Seq(3,6,4,1,9,5), Seq(3,5))
//res0: Seq[(String, Seq[Int])] = Seq((@-3,Seq(-2147483648, 3)), (5-@,Seq(5, 2147483647)), (3-5,Seq(3, 5)), (@-3,Seq(-2147483648, 3)), (5-@,Seq(5, 2147483647)), (3-5,Seq(3, 5)))
```

Comment: This is great. You are right that this minimal case is good enough. However, I do not want to get the discrete group twice.

Comment: Again, I don't _quite_ follow your meaning. If you want the result `Seq` to contain only those `bins` represented in the data, but each of those `bins` only once, then just throw a `.distinct` on the end of the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you want but you could try to do a `groupBy`:

```
scala> val x=Seq(1,7,5,4,6,3).groupBy(_/3)
x: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[Int]] = Map(2 -> List(7, 6), 1 -> List(5, 4, 3), 0 -> List(1))
```

So the first bin contains `1`:

```
scala> x(0)
res6: Seq[Int] = List(1)
```

The second bin contains `5,4,3`:

```
scala> x(1)
res7: Seq[Int] = List(5, 4, 3)
```

And the last bin contains `7,6`:

```
scala> x(2)
res8: Seq[Int] = List(7, 6)
```

Or you could use `org.apache.spark.ml.feature.QuantileDiscretizer` if you're dealing with columns on a dataframe https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#quantilediscretizer